# cannot figure out how to use an if statement to check all elements in an array with a callback and check if they are all true

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, callback

I'm not sure how to check every element to the callback and check if they are all true; I am also quite new to trying to code so sorry if it looks bad.

Write a function `myEvery` that accepts an array and a callback as arguments.
The function should return a boolean indicating whether or not all elements of
the array return true when passed into the callback.
Do not use the built in Array#every

```
let myEvery = function(arr, cb) {
   let bool = false;
   if (cb(arr) === true) {
      bool = true;
   }
   return bool;
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `for..` to loop through the array and return false immediately if the callback returns falsy value. Not that checking whether all array items are `true` should be done in the callback not in `myEvery`. All array filter/check methods work with truthy/false values returned from callbacks. Learn here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Also note that for checking whether array items truthy/false you could use `Boolean()` which is a constructor of a wrapper object of a boolean primitive which is used then as a true/false condition.

```js
let myEvery = function(arr, cb) {
   for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if (!cb(arr[i])) {
          return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
};

const arr = ['YOUR CASE: CHECKING IF ALL true',
() => myEvery([true, true, true, true, true], item => item === true),

'CHECKING true/false FROM CALLBACK',
() => myEvery([1, 1, 1, 0, 1], item => item === 1),

'CHECKING FALSY',
() => myEvery([1, 1, 1, 0, 1], item => item),

'CHECKING FALSY WITH ARRAY::EVERY()',
() => [1, 1, 1, 0, 1].every(item => item),

'CHECKING WITH BOOLEAN()',
() => myEvery([1, 1, 1, 0, 1], Boolean),

'CHECKING ALL TRUE',
() => myEvery([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], item => item === 1)];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2){
  console.log(arr[i]);
  console.log(arr[i+1].toString().slice(6));
  console.log(arr[i+1]());
}
```

Here's a log of what happens:

```js
let myEvery = function(arr, cb) {
   for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      const result = cb(arr[i]);
      console.log('result of callback for', arr[i], '=>', result);
      if (!result) {
          console.log('returning false');
          return false;
      }
   }
   console.log('all array items are ok, returning true');
   return true;
};

console.log(myEvery([1, 1, 1, 0, 1], item => item === 1));
console.log(myEvery([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], item => item === 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kooilnc's response for `[].every()` should be used in such cases, but as for an understanding about creating callbacks & functions that use callbacks, or validation functions within conditionals, I'll write a little something that helped me understand them better.

This question is not really a callback context, but just a use of functions in a 'first-class' manner. Callbacks, to me, seemed to be designed and named for their ability to call a function/method when their execution context has completed, but def not limited to only this.

To give an example of callbacks, and checking the values returned by the "callback" or "higher-order function" see below for an amateur example.

```
let myArr = [0,2,4,6,8,9,10,11,12,14];

let isEvenOdd = function(val) {
  console.log('checking if value is even or odd.');
  return (val % 2 === 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
}

let callback = function() {
  console.log('done!\n\tlogged within the cb!');
}

let firstOddValue = function(arr, validator, cb) {
  let tmp = arr;
  let val = tmp.shift();
  let eo = validator(val);
  if (eo === 'even') {
    console.log(`${val} is even`);
    return firstOddValue(tmp, validator, cb);
  } else if (eo === 'odd') {
    console.log(`${val} is odd`);
  }
  return cb();
}

firstOddValue(myArr, isEvenOdd, callback);
```

Every time the runtime (or compiler depending on the language/context) approaches a function call within another function, the js runtime will pause the execution of the current function stack, create a new execution stack and run the new one until completes or returns a value, after which it resumes the previous execution context, etc.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which asks how to implement a homemade `.every()`. See [answer].

Comment: actually, it parses all elements using recursion & shows an example of using callbacks. He stated he is new, I was new not too long ago and know the trouble areas. He's not coding the next google, he is learning concepts, not apis. Not everything is black & white, not everyone knows how to word their questions in a way that professionals know how to answer so they understand. Simply referring to a method, doesn't teach a thing.

Comment: Still, this is not an answer. It shows an example of a high-level recursive function, yes, but that does something completely different from `.every()`.